# Python: Scraping special Characters Writing to CSV

Tags: python, csv, python-unicode

Hello I am trying to scrape a website and its going fine, till the point I try to save the data into a csv via csv module `writer`. I traced back to the data and find out that `7 años` is the string which isn't allowing the data to store properly.

I READ A LOT ON THIS TOPIC BEFORE POSTING... BUT COULDN'T GRASP THE CONCEPT.

Python is throwing some encoding error which got me to reading and I found that `csv` module isn't capable of `unicode`.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: *"some encoding error"* – be more specific. Show your code. Show the exact error.

Comment: You can use the csv module with unicode, if you set the encoding of your script to unicode.

One way to do this is to add these lines: 

  >>  import sys 
  >>  reload(sys) 
  >>  sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

Comment: Thanks! That did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following solution

```
def sanitize_string(string):
    return string.replace('\t', '')
```

Try to encode the string using encode function

```
your_variable = sanitize_string("your string")
your_variable.encode('utf8')
```

Hope this will help you.